# Pressing enter in a textbox to move the focus to the next textbox without selecting the text

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `WinForm` with two `TextBox`es. I want to move the focus from the first `TextBox`to the next one after the user has pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd>. My code looks like this:

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        SomeCustomMethod();
        textBox2.Focus();
    }
}
```

Now if the user has entered some text before pressing enter, it first selects the whole text as shown below:

[image]

And then by pressing enter for the second time, the focus moves to the next `TextBox`. I don't want that. I want it to go straight to the next `TextBox` without selecting the whole text of the first `TextBox`. I also tested it with `KeyUp` event and it didn't work. Help!

Comment: What does the `SomeCustomMethod()` do? I don't recall textboxes just selecting its full text when losing focus.

Comment: using your code (minus the somecustommethod call) mine moved to the next box on pressing enter..... and highlighted box2.. not box1...

Comment: I'm the same as BugFinder, I used everything except "SomeCustomMethod()" and it worked as you want it.

Comment: Same here. I suspect something in `SomeCustomMethod()` selects the text

Comment: I think I'm a little unclear.  You want it to switch between `TextBox`'s by pressing the Enter key, but you don't want it to select the text from the box when moving to the next box, correct?

Comment: And can you put up the code from `SomeCustomMethod()`

Comment: @GeoffOverfieldYes, that's right

Comment: You are all right. If I comment SomeCustomMethod() it works fine. That method triggers the left button we have in our footer which sends Json to the server

Comment: I like to avoid sharing the code of the method because it uses many different parts of our core library. If I want to share them all it's going to be way too long.

Comment: Sharing the entire code is not necessary. It would suffice to share that portion which would make the problem reproduceble . So that we could copy paste the code into a blank project, run it on Windows 10 and produce the same result

Answer (score 1):

The text inside the `TextBox` can only be selected if the focus is on it. 
When you say:

> "Now if the user has entered some text before pressing enter, it first selects the whole text "

Then you quite probably do it yourself. Please hit <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> and search your entire project for :

```
your_textbox_Name.Select
```

Then remove this line and your ghostly auto selection should be gone

Comment: I don't use your_textbox_Name.Select. And I just looked into the SomeCustomMethod() of our library and I didn't see such method there either.

Comment: nowhere in your project you focus the textbox and do a select? What is the operating system that you are using? I looked on the net but could not find anything like auto selection of text.

Comment: the closest was this [post](https://channel9.msdn.com/Forums/TechOff/410195-C--TextBox--How-to-prevent-select-OnFocus)

Comment: I've never used the Select method anywhere. We might have used it somewhere deep inside our core library but I haven't used it. I'm using Windows 10